# Using Identity Server for Authentication with ASP.NET Web App and .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

Our company has custom-built Identity Server, which is used by a few of our web applications for authentication. I am trying to use our Identity Server with a newly created ASP.NET Core Web App, using the .NET 6 framework. I am trying to use the predefined OIDC URLs, without having to write the code myself.

The authentication is mostly working; for example, if I add [Authorize] to a certain Razor PageModel, it will automatically redirect to the Authority URL, and then return to that page upon authentication and be logged in.

What I am having trouble with is this: I cannot seem to get the automatic sign out to work. I am trying to use either of the predefined OIDC signout URLs (signout-oidc or signout-callback-oidc), but I seem to be missing something. I am also having trouble finding good sample code or clear documentation to help debug the issue.

I have also tried using OIDC events - for example "OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect":

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", async options =>
    {
        options.Authority = testIdentitySettings.Authority;
        options.SignedOutRedirectUri = testIdentitySettings.SignedOutRedirectUri;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = testIdentitySettings.RequireHttpsMetadata ?? true;
        options.ClientId = testIdentitySettings.ClientId;
        options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
        options.Scope.Add("roles");
        options.SaveTokens = true;

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name",
            RoleClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"
        };

        options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = async (context) =>
        {
            await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");

            var redirUrl = context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri;

            var prop = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = redirUrl
            };

            await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc", prop);

            context.Response.Redirect(redirUrl);
            context.HandleResponse();
        };
    });
```

This almost seems to work. It does redirect to my SignedOutRedirectUri (/LoggedOut), and when I check the User on that page, the User.Identity shows IsAuthenticated = false, and has zero claims; however, if I then load the home page (/), the User.Identity is back as authenticated with all the claims.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Logout example, you could refer to the code below.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Auth0.AspNetCore.Authentication;

public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public async Task Logout()
    {
        var authenticationProperties = new LogoutAuthenticationPropertiesBuilder()
            // Indicate here where Auth0 should redirect the user after a logout.
            // Note that the resulting absolute Uri must be added to the
            // **Allowed Logout URLs** settings for the app.
            .WithRedirectUri(Url.Action("Index", "Home"))
            .Build();

        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(Auth0Constants.AuthenticationScheme, authenticationProperties);
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
}
```

Reference: [Logout](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet-core/01-login#logout)

If the issue persists, you could try to make tests with the code sample below to reduce the `ExpireTimeSpan` in the `AddCookie` configuration.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(/* ... */)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            });
        // ...
    }
```

For more detailed information, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752211/10309381).

Comment: This, and Tore's updated answer, sort of worked. It logged me out and I ended up on our Identity Server logout page (account/logout). Deepak, your "RedirectUri" didn't seem to work; I tried the above, and also a hard-coded URL to a logged out page on my site, but neither redirect worked.

I was actually hoping to use the "signout-oidc-logout" URL, which I feel should automatically handle all of the above, but I'm at a loss on how to get that to work.

Comment: I figured out a solution that works for me. Basically, Tore and Deepak were both right about the need for the SignOutAsync calls, but I ended up manually building the logout URL (instead of using signout-oidc). The URL looks something like this: https://identityserver/connect/endsession?id_token_hint={idToken}&post_logout_redirect_uri={redirectUri}. I am going to give you both credit for the answer and close this, but I still wish I knew why the signout-oidc doesn't do all this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this to do the signout:

```
[Authorize]
/// <summary>
/// Do the actual logout
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task DoLogout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

I don't think you need to use the OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect handler.

In your case, as you have renamed the schemes, the logout method should be:

```
[Authorize]
/// <summary>
/// Do the actual logout
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task DoLogout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and received the following runtime error:

InvalidOperationException: No sign-out authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'OpenIdConnect'. The registered sign-out schemes are: Cookies, oidc. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookie("OpenIdConnect",...)?

I was really hoping to use the built-in signout-callback-oidc (or even signout-oidc). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I updated my answer. as I forgot you had renamed the schemes.